# column level data lineage

Tags: oracle11g, reverse-engineering, data-lineage

I have a stored proc which creates table Z from Table X and Y as below.

```
Create table Z as (select X.1 as Z.1,
X.2 as Z.2,
Y.2+X.2 as Z.3,
Y.3 as Z.4,
Y.5 as Z.5,
'dummy' as Z.6 from X,Y)
```

I need a lineage tool which maps not only table X,Y to Z but also Z.1 to X.1, Z.3 to X2 and Y2 , 'dummy' to Z.6 and henceforth.

Is there any tool (free or licensed) which can do this column level mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Look for SQLDep.. Although its licensed. Also for Travidis blogs.